# Use a Stream Lookup but with '%%' in string and not '='

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Is there any way to find a record but having a '%%' like filter?

I'm using a table input to return information from a table, but I have another reference table to cross the information.

My problem is that it´s not a unique[image] string,

so I need to like '% content%'

Comment: Unable to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace both your "Stream lookup" and "Table input" steps by a "Database Lookup" step. In comparator select "Like" and in "Field1" set the condition you want to use to retrieve the records that match.